# extjs change grid color cell for more columns

Tags: extjs

I need to change two different columns with a color, the field **change** work fine, but I can't change the field **name** too.

I tried the bold but doesn't work.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        header: 'Change',
        dataIndex: 'change',
        tdCls: 'x-change-cell'
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function(record, index) {
            var c = record.get('change');
            if (c < 0) {
                return 'price-fall';
            } else if (c > 0) {
                return 'price-rise';
            };
            //DOES'NT WORK HERE 
            **
            var c = record.get('name');
            if (name == 'GIO') {
                return 'color-gio';
            } else {
                return 'color-other';
            }; **

        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Is there a typo? I believe the `c` variable declaration and the `name` variable used in the if statement, bellow the "does not work" comment should have the same name.

Comment: `getRowClass()` is called for each record updated or added. So the class will be applied to the whole row. After change field , the function is returning and ur name code is never executed. Better to use renderer in column.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`getRowClass`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.view.Table.html#method-getRowClass) used [`renderer`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer) config of [`gridcolumn`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html) because you want to change `cell` color not the `row`.

> **getRowClass** Override this function to apply custom CSS classes to rows during rendering. This function should return the CSS class name (or empty string '' for none) that will be added to the row's wrapping element.

In this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2h3e), I have create a demo using `renderer` config inside of `gridcolumn`.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'demostore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'change'],
            data: [{
                name: 'GIO',
                email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-111-1224',
                change: -1
            }, {
                name: 'Bart',
                email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1234',
                change: 10
            }, {
                name: 'GIO',
                email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1244',
                change: 20
            }, {
                name: 'Marge',
                email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1254',
                change: -20
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Change cell color based on record',
            store: 'demostore',

            columns: [{
                header: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1,
                renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex) {
                    metaData.tdCls = record.get('name') == 'GIO' ? 'price-fall' : 'price-rise'
                    return value;
                }
            }, {
                header: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                header: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                header: 'Change',
                dataIndex: 'change',
                renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex) {
                    metaData.tdCls = record.get('change') > 0 ? 'color-other' : 'color-gio';
                    return value;
                }
            }],
            height: 200,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

**CSS SNIPPET**

```
<style>
    .price-fall {
        background: red;
    }

    .price-rise {
        background: green;
    }

    .color-gio {
        background: gray;
    }

    .color-other {
        background: yellow;
    }

</style>
```